# Query on the result of another query giving errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a query on the result set of another query but getting errors which I cannot understand. I'm sure it's something small but I'm somehow missing it. This is the query:

```
SELECT
  RLID,
  NAME,
  GROUP_CONCAT(SUBQUERY.Items SEPARATOR ', ') AS Items
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    `rel_menu_item`.`ID` AS `RLID`,
    `menu`.`Name` AS `Menu_Name`,
    `item`.`Name` AS `Items`
  FROM
    `rel_menu_item`
  JOIN
    `menu` ON `menu`.`ID` = `rel_menu_item`.`Menu_ID`
  JOIN
    `item` ON `item`.`ID` = `rel_menu_item`.`Item_ID`
) AS SUBQUERY
GROUP BY
  SUBQUERY.Name
```

**Errors:**

> 3 errors were found during analysis.
>
> 1. An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 90)
> 2. Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 90)
> 3. This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 95)

Comment: it is `Menu_Name` not `Name`

Answer (score 1):

I found the errors. Here is the correct query:

```
SELECT
  SUBQUERY.RLID,
  SUBQUERY.Menu_Name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(SUBQUERY.Items SEPARATOR ', ') AS Items
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    rel_menu_item.ID AS RLID,
    menu.Name AS Menu_Name,
    item.Name AS Items
  FROM
    rel_menu_item
  JOIN
    menu ON menu.ID = rel_menu_item.Menu_ID
  JOIN
    item ON item.ID = rel_menu_item.Item_ID
) AS SUBQUERY
GROUP BY
  SUBQUERY.Menu_Name
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have a subquery at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should be writing this query without a subquery at all:

```
SELECT m.Id as RLID, m.Name as Menu_Name
      GROUP_CONCAT(i.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS Items
FROM rel_menu_item rmi JOIN
     menu m
     ON m.ID = rmi.Menu_ID JOIN
     item i
     ON i.ID = rmi.Item_ID
GROUP BY m.Id, m.Name;
```

Notes:

- The subquery is not needed.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- It is better to use the column from the primary key table `menu.id` rather than from the references foreign key.  It doesn't really make a difference with inner joins, but it does make a difference with outer joins; hence, it is a bad practice.
- You should include *all* non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.